# MySQL get last N rows and find percentage

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table which has thousands of Rows and columns of char values:

```
+----+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | date     | time     | Server1 | Server2 | Server3 | Server4 | Server5 | Server6 |
+----+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 52 | 12/02/18 | 14:00:00 |       1 |       1 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 51 | 12/02/18 | 13:55:00 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       0 |       1 |
| 50 | 12/02/18 | 13:52:00 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 49 | 12/02/18 | 13:50:00 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       0 |       1 |
| 48 | 12/02/18 | 13:45:00 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
| 47 | 12/02/18 | 13:40:00 |       1 |       0 |       1 |       0 |       1 |       1 |
| 46 | 12/02/18 | 13:35:00 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       0 |       1 |
| 45 | 12/02/18 | 13:30:00 |       1 |       1 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 44 | 12/02/18 | 13:27:50 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       0 |       1 |       1 |
| 43 | 12/02/18 | 13:27:14 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
+----+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I did a lot of research but couldn't find anything on the web, i need to print out the last 5 rows and get the the percentage of 1 and 0 on each server column, something like the below or any way that will show them.

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      | Server1 | Server2 | Server3 | Server4 | Server5 | Server6 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    0 |       10|       2 |       7 |   8.443 |  11.155 |  99.921 |
|    1 |  11.411 |  12.443 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Thanks..

Comment: Why isn't 0 percentage plus 1 percentage 100 together?

Comment: What do your sample results have to do with "print[ing] out the last 5 rows"?  This doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: hi, sorry that was a typo, this table is being updated every 5 minuets with the data, so i need to get the percentage of 1's and 0's in the last 5 rows.. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most visually appetizing query, but we could just take a union of two queries which find the stats for 0 and 1 separately.  The subqueries below I have aliased as `t` use `LIMIT` to identify the last 5 rows in your table (alternatively the first five rows, as ordered descending by date and time).

```
SELECT 0 AS stat,
    100.0* SUM(CASE WHEN Server1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS Server1,
    100.0* SUM(CASE WHEN Server2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS Server2,
    100.0* SUM(CASE WHEN Server3 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS Server3,
    100.0* SUM(CASE WHEN Server4 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS Server4,
    100.0* SUM(CASE WHEN Server5 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS Server5,
    100.0* SUM(CASE WHEN Server6 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS Server6
FROM
(
    SELECT Server1, Server2, Server3, Server4, Server5, Server6
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
    LIMIT 5
) t
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,
    100.0* SUM(Server1) / COUNT(*),
    100.0* SUM(Server2) / COUNT(*),
    100.0* SUM(Server3) / COUNT(*),
    100.0* SUM(Server4) / COUNT(*),
    100.0* SUM(Server5) / COUNT(*),
    100.0* SUM(Server6) / COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT Server1, Server2, Server3, Server4, Server5, Server6
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
    LIMIT 5
) t;
```

Note: I assume that your `date` column is actually a date, and not just text.  If it's text, then you'll have to first convert it to a date using `STR_TO_DATE`, e.g.

```
STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%y')
```

Comment: Note you can make it prettier with "avg(Server1 = 0)" instead of sum(case...)/count(*), since mysql handles bools just as ints.  Final value would be different in case of nulls, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @peufeu Good point, but I seldom find myself using that syntax because not all databases support it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen another question if you don't mind, is it possible to round/limit digits of the decimals in percentage? e.g. for 99.875944 i want it to display as 99.890

Comment: Use `ROUND(99.875944, 3)` or handle this in your presentation layer.